# Stop peep notification sound in android 13

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Good day gentleman,

I have been a user for old android versions such as android 9 fir quit a period of time , now I switched to Samsung S22 ultra with android 13 and found a really annoying feature that I really need to get rid of .

My problem is whenever you in a call , all notifications sounds and turned into small BEEP sound instead of the normal notification sound.

I make long phone calls and in this case I lose many important notifications.

Could you please tell me how to disable that?

I tried an app called Notifications sound manager , it is working okay but when I'm not in a call , I just need to disable its service in order not to get duplicate notification sounds which is really annoying.

I just need the normal notification sounds of each app